# in python i want to get two number ,repeat first number as much as the second is

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a problem with a code. I want to define a function that gets two integer number for example (`x`, `y`). Then as much as `y` is, `x` repeat and finally I want to sum them.

for example:

If the function gets `(4, 5)`, the result should be like this:

`44444+4444+444+44+4`

or if `(2, 3)`, the result should be this:

```
222+22+2=246
```

Comment: *I have a problem with a code* - I don't see any code

Comment: def f(x,y):return sum([int(str(x)*y) for y in range(1,y+1)])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do replication to your data when you're multiplying `str` with `int`.

For Instance, If I want to repeat word **`hello` 3 times**:-

```
print("hello " * 3)
```

**OUTPUT**

`hello hello hello`

#### Question Code

```py
def fact(x, y):
    alist = []
    for i in range(1, y+1):
      alist.append(int(str(x)*i))
    
    summ= sum(alist)
    print(alist, "= ", summ)
   
      
fact(2, 3)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[2, 22, 222] =  246

[Program finished]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot . Is there anyway to not use a list? just produce a series of numbers and sum them?

Comment: @mjshvi, actually this what i did there... I appended the series of needed format numbers then i summed them using`sum()` function. Run the code and you will understand what's happening, i added a format to the output so you can understand how it works. Please, if this answer helps you, please mark my answer as the **Right Answer**

Comment: @mjshvi ... Not using a list, are tou need the summation only without the declaration of the numbers?

Comment: To provide the series of numbers without storing them will provide insufficient performance... You can do that in your case but if you don't to need to provide the numbers you're submitting to show the process how it goes.

Comment: I just want to return the sum

Comment: Easy, you can play with the code like you want. Instead of  the two print. Return `return sum (alist)`